# AWS Cognito Global sign-out vs non-global sign-out

Tags: amazon-cognito

I would like to use AWS Cognito with multiple devices (iOS, android, web) and would like to be able to sign out of a certain device, like my phone, but not be signed out of my web account. I do NOT want to do a global sign-out. 1. Is this possible with AWS Cognito? 2. How can I achieve this functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this functionality can be achieved by using Cognito's [LOGOUT](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/logout-endpoint.html) Endpoint. A sample cURL request is as follows:

```
## Set constants ##
CLIENT_ID="USER_POOL_CLIENT_ID"
REDIRECT_URI="https://example.com/"

## Hit /logout endpoint ##
curl -v "https://${AUTH_DOMAIN}/logout?client_id=${CLIENT_ID}&logout_uri=${REDIRECT_URI}"
```

You can implement this programmatically in your mobile or web application as well.

Comment: So to do this I would need to add multiple app clients in Cognito correct? That way each client can be logged in and out without affecting the other?

Answer (score 0):

Sort of. The best you can get is to delete your `refresh_token` and any `id_token`s from your cookies. If you don't have any of those tokens shared between devices (highly likely), then you'll get most of what you're looking for.

Cognito really *should have* a logout endpoint that takes a `refresh_token` and kills it. Without this, if you've shared tokens for external usage, those get to keep using 'em even after logout.

Comment: it has, called `REVOCATION Endpoint`. You need to give `token` in body, which is the refresh token that the client wants to revoke. Access tokens issued from the refresh token are also revoked.  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/revocation-endpoint.html